# User Profile Synchronization Error

Tags: user-profile-service, configuration, sharepoint-standard

I am installing SharePoint 2010 using AutoSPInstaller which is failing when creating a user profile service application with below error.  I have provided Install account dbcreator and security admin roles and local administrator on SharePoint box.

During installation SPT_Farm is also added to local administrator on SharePoint server. Even then the UPA is failing.

**Questions: Do we have to provide any permission to SPT_Farm account in SQL?**

> Creating User Profile Service Application as DOMAIN\SPT_Farm...
>   New-SPProfileServiceApplication : The EXECUTE permission was denied on
>   the obje ct 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. At
>   C:\Users\SPT_admin\AppData\Local\Temp\AutoSPInstaller-ScriptBlock.ps1:3
>   c har:56
>   + $newProfileServiceApp = New-SPProfileServiceApplication <<<<  -Name "User Pro file Service Application" -ApplicationPool "SharePoint
>   Hosted Services" -Profil eDBServer daa3014snd -ProfileDBName
>   SPT_UserProfile -ProfileSyncDBServer daa3014snd -ProfileSyncDBName
>   SPT_Profile_Sync -SocialDBServer daa3014snd -SocialD BName
>   SPT_Profile_Social -MySiteHostLocation http://mysites.contoso.com:8080
>   -MySiteManagedPath "personal"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...viceApplication:
>   SPCmdletNewProfileServiceApplication)
>   [New-SPProfileServiceApplication], S   qlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PowerShell.
>   SPCmdletNewProfileServiceApplication

Comment: What kind of permissions does your SharePoint Farm account have in the SQL Instance?

Comment: My Farm account doesn't have any access in SQL.. I don't see anywhere that Farm account needs access in SQL for User Profile configuration.. All the blogs talk about having administrator access on the SharePoint server where I am configuring UPS..

Answer (score 2):

**Do we have to provide any permission to SPT_Farm account in SQL?**

- The farm account must have

  - `Dbcreator` fixed server role.
  - `Securityadmin` fixed server role.
  - `db_owner` for all SharePoint databases.
  - Membership in the WSS_CONTENT_APPLICATION_POOLS role for the SharePoint server farm configuration database.
  - Membership in the WSS_CONTENT_APPLICATION_POOLS role for the SharePoint_Admin content database.

For more details check [Account permissions and security settings in SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx)

Comment: Besides the above, Make sure the account has SharePoint_Shell_Access role on SharePoint_Config to run scripts